# python loop only works after putting code in a function

Tags: python, validation, loops

In a Python 3 script, I have a part where I have a for loop, where I want to do stuff and then do a validation check. If it does NOT pass the validation check, I want to skip processing the rest of the loop and just move on to the next item in the loop. If it passes the validation check, I want the script to do some more stuff and then perform another validation check where it does the same as the first validation check; if it does not pass validation, skip the rest of the code in the for loop and move on to the next iteration of the loop; if it passes validation, keep processing code in the loop.  I might do this 3-5 times within the loop.  But here's the thing...

When I set up my script like this, it does NOT work as intended:

```
for example in examples:

    ##### do some stuff here
    ##### then have a VALIDATION CHECK here

    if "dates" in paydata:
        continue

    ##### then do do some more stuff here
    ##### then have another VALIDATION CHECK here

    if 'Payment' in pay_plan:
        continue

    ##### then do do some more stuff here
    ##### then have another VALIDATION CHECK here

    if 'Plan' in pay_plan:
        continue

    ##### continue on with the script and do some stuff here, etc.
```

But, when I basically put my if statements into functions and then my code looks like the following (with my if statements based on the return of the function), it works as intended. My question, then, is why do the continue statements do one thing (NOT work as intended) in the first code example but DO work in the second code example (work as intended). What am I missing in this "head-scratcher"?

```
##### create validation-check functions

def func_1(id, paydata):
    if "dates" in paydata:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def func_2(id, pay_plan):
    if 'Payment' in pay_plan:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def func_3(id, plan):
    if 'Plan' in plan:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

for example in examples:

    #####
    ##### do some stuff here
    #####

    ##### then have a VALIDATION CHECK here

    md_check = multiple_dates(id, paydata)
    if md_check == True:
        continue

    #####
    ##### then do do some more stuff here
    #####

    ##### then have another VALIDATION CHECK here

    on_pp = on_payment_plan(id, pay_plan)
    if on_pp == True:
        continue

    #####
    ##### then do do some more stuff here
    #####

    ##### then have another VALIDATION CHECK here

    on_pp = on_payment_plan(id, plan)
    if on_pp == True:
        continue

#####
##### continue on with the script and do some stuff here
#####
```

Comment: Could you place a working example that reproduces what you're explaining.  It's not clear how `paydata` or `pay_plan` are being defined and manipulated from your examples.  Are there other loops within your main loop?  Because a continue will only break out of the containing loop.

Comment: Not sure if it's actually an error in your code, but you have this in your second snippet:  `def func_3(id, plan):    if 'Plan' in pay_plan:` - I assume it needs to be `if 'Plan' in plan`

Answer (score 0):

`continue` does not do what you think it does. The keyword `continue` sends the loop back to the beginning. It's not to be used to allow a loop to continue as the name implies it's for when a condition has been met but you need the loop to continue going.

To make your loop keep going a better check would be in the format:

```
if not md_check:
        break
```

This inverses your logic and exits the loop if your condition is not present. The same is applicable here:

```
if on_pp == True:
        continue
```

Should be:

```
if not on_pp:
    break
```

A small working example to show how `continue` works:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> while x < 50:
    if not x & 1:
        print('{} is even'.format(x))
        x += 1
    else:
        print('{} is odd'.format(x))
        x += 1
        continue
    print('this only prints if x is even')


1 is odd
2 is even
this only prints if x is even
3 is odd
4 is even
this only prints if x is even
5 is odd
6 is even
this only prints if x is even
7 is odd
8 is even
this only prints if x is even
9 is odd
10 is even
# snipped for brevity
```

Comment: I think I understand that "continue" should stop any more processing for that particular iteration of the loop and the next iteration of the loop will immediately begin to process. That's what I want in this case. But, even though both examples above use the keyword continue for each validation check, in the first example, even though the first validation might process as true, the next two validation checks are processed, but in the second example, the next two validation checks are not processed. The next iteration of the loop is what happens (and what I want to happen). Why the difference?

Comment: Are you sure the first Boolean is evaluating as `True`?

Comment: Yes (well, the first, second or third...depends on the data in each particular iteration). That's the thing I cannot understand. There is basically no difference between the first and second examples above, in that "if" whatever is "true", what happens next is different. The if's are in the same indentation and so are the continues. Hence, the "head-scratcher".